# Designing a button with an inset icon style in Photoshop?

Tags: icon, photoshop-effects

I am using the [Glyphish icon set](http://www.glyphish.com/), and I am trying to achieve an ["inset" look of the icon in a button in](http://dribbble.com/system/users/5800/screenshots/130585/shot_1300124934.jpg) Photoshop. Any recommendation on how best achieve it?

Comment: Hi GeorgeU, welcome to GD.  This forum is trying to target advanced Design-related questions.  There are several users who are happy to help the odd tool-related questions, but this isn't really the place to ask for a basic tutorial.  Have you tried any of the many tutorials already available on other websites?

Comment: I did try, and couldn't find anything specific. I am sorry if this was too begineer for here.

Comment: Did you see this tutorial?  http://www.absolutecross.com/tutorials/photoshop/inset-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would say try playing with a border and internal drop shadow. In the example you posted each of the buttons has a 1px solid border which is broken with a light drop shadow. Some of the boxes seem to actually be using a type of outer glow instead of box shadow.

Reduce the opacity on that a lot, maybe 10-30% and very light coloring. There is a gradient style you can use as well. But I'm guessing you know about that if you're attempting to construct such a button style!

For more you can see this tutorial :

[Photoshop Inset button](http://www.gamexe.net/photoshop/inset-buttons/)

hope this will help...

Comment: Jake - thanks for taking the time to answer my question!